Vercel Build Fails: Cannot Find Module 'autoprefixer' with Next.js 14.1.4
I'm working on a Next.js project deployed on Vercel, but my build fails with the following error related to autoprefixer:
Error: Cannot find module 'autoprefixer'
Require stack:
- /vercel/path0/node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/config/blocks/css/plugins.js
...


The issue occurs during the production build process after Prisma generates the client. Below is the relevant part of my package.json:
"dependencies": {
  "next": "14.1.4",
  "@prisma/client": "^5.16.1",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  "autoprefixer": "^10.4.20",
  "postcss": "^8.4.41",
  "tailwindcss": "^3.4.10",
  ...
}

And here is my layout.tsx:
import type { Metadata } from "next";
import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import "./globals.css";
import { Providers } from "./providers";
import { SpeedInsights } from "@vercel/speed-insights/next";

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Studio Pinya",
  description: "Admininstration panel for Studio Pinya",
};

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Providers>
          {children} <SpeedInsights />
        </Providers>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}

The error seems to be related to a missing autoprefixer module during the build. I've tried reinstalling dependencies and clearing the cache, but the issue persists. Any insights on how to resolve this would be greatly appreciated!
I expected the Vercel build process to correctly recognize and use autoprefixer during the production build, without any issues related to missing modules. I anticipated that after clearing the cache and reinstalling dependencies, the build would proceed without errors, especially since it works fine locally.
Thank You

I'm facing a similar issue as well. Were you able to find a solution to it
